# How to make a Button continually call a function when held down (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift, timer, sprite-kit

I'm making a game using sprite kit and I want my Character to move across the screen when you hold down the left/right move button. The problem is that he only moves when the button is tapped, not held. I have looked everywhere for a solution but nothing seems to work!

Here's my code;

```
class Button: SKNode
{
   var defaultButton: SKSpriteNode // defualt state
   var activeButton: SKSpriteNode  // active state

   var timer = Timer()

   var action: () -> Void

   //default constructor
   init(defaultButtonImage: String, activeButtonImage: String, buttonAction: @escaping () -> Void )
   {
      //get the images for both button states
      defaultButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: defaultButtonImage)
      activeButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: activeButtonImage)

      //hide it while not in use
      activeButton.isHidden = true 
      action = buttonAction

      super.init()

      isUserInteractionEnabled = true

      addChild(defaultButton)
      addChild(activeButton)    
   }

   //When user touches button
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
   {
      action()

      //using timer to repeatedly call action, doesnt seem to work...
      self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(getter: Button.action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

      //swtich the image of our button
      activeButton.isHidden = false
      defaultButton.isHidden = true

   }

   code..........
```

In my game scene...

```
// *** RIGHT MOVEMENT ***
      let rightMovementbutton = Button(defaultButtonImage: "arrow", activeButtonImage: "arrowActive", buttonAction:
      {

         let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 15, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
         self.player.run(moveAction)


      })
```

Comment: As the name specifies, `touchBegan` will only be called when the touch started... you should update your logic to set some boolean value on began/ended.

Comment: use `touchesMoved `  method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know when the button is touched because `touchesBegan` is called. You then have to set a flag to indicate that the button is pressed.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    if leftButton.containsPoint(touch.locationInNode(self)) {
        leftButtonIsPressed = true
    }
    if rightButton.containsPoint(touch.locationInNode(self)) {
        rightButtonIsPressed = true
    }
}
```

In `update()`, call your function that flag is true:

```
update() {
   if leftButtonIsPressed == true {
        moveLeft()
    }

   if rightButtonIsPressed == true {
        moveRight()
    }

}
```

You set the flag to false when `touchesEnded` is called for that button:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    if leftButton.containsPoint(touch.locationInNode(self)) {
        leftButtonIsPressed = false
    }
    if rightButton.containsPoint(touch.locationInNode(self)) {
        rightButtonIsPressed = flase
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

As pointed out by KoD, a cleaner way to do this (for movement buttons) is with `SKAction` which removes the need for the flag:

1. Define `SKActions` for `moveTo x:0` and `moveTo x:frame.width` in
   `didMoveTo(View:)`
2. In `touchesBegan`, run the correct SKAction on the correct object
   specifying a key for the SKAction.
3. In `touchesEnded`, remove the relevant SKAction.

You'll have to do some maths to calculate how many points your object will have to move and then set a duration for the SKAction based upon this distance and a movement speed (in points per second).

Alternatively, (thanks to KnightOfDragons for this) create a `SKAction.MoveBy x:` which moves a small distance (based upon your desired movement speed) and with a duration of 1/60s. Repeat this action forever (`SKAction.repeatForever`) when the button is touched and remove the repeating SKAction when the button is released.

Comment: You got my up vote, But I wouldn't even bother with flags,  just assign a repeat forever action on touches begin, and remove the action on touch ended/touch cancelled

Comment: @Knight0fDragon - good idea. I was concentrating on his desire to call a function, but your way is cleaner - I'm planning on doing this in an update to my Space Invaders game (in the App Store now *cough* Space Invaders 2016 *cough*) by doing a moveTo x:0 for left and moveTo x:frame.width for right and then removing that move action in touchesEnded.

Comment: Dont do move to, do move by,  moveto means inconsistent movement based on distance

Comment: @Knight0fDragon - Does it make a difference? You still have to do some maths to get the right speed.

Comment: no you do not,  if you say moveby 10 at duration .01666 in a repeat  forever loop this means every frame it will move 10, if you say moveto width at a specified duration, then if the distance is small, he will move slower than if the distance was great

Comment: @Knight0fDragon - OK, so you're saying use repeated SKActions with a duration of 1/60s.

Comment: yes, or multiply your movement by 60 for a duration of 1 second,  this may actually be better to handle any lag spikes now that I think about it

Comment: @SteveIves I think it's better to run a single `moveTo` action that moves to the view's edge with a calculated duration (based on the distance) instead of running multiple `moveBy` actions, repeatedly.

Comment: @Epsilon as is usual with SpriteKit, there's more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: Hey guys! Just wanted to report back and say that it worked! Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @Epsilon would be a good test, constantly calculating with a square root when swapping left and right button versus a block already in memory just being repeatedly called

Comment: @Knight0fDragon the distance calculation doesn't require a square root if the character is moving from side to side. I'm concerned about how smooth the transition between repeated `moveBy` actions and how well you can control the character's speed.

Comment: @Epsilon, true, wasn't thinking only side to side only needed 1 axis , but if the only fear is the repeated calls then instead of multiplying by 60 for a duration of 1, just multiply by 60 * duration.  Since this only needs to be done once we can make it a constant.  So the only thing that would be throttling us is  a branch to ensure player does not leave bounds, so a test would need to be made with a moveBy + constraint vs a moveTo to determine which is faster (Although I highly doubt this would really matter speed wise, I would guess nanosecond differences here)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon constraints are tested ~60 times a second. You're using up CPU cycles needlessly.

Comment: @Epsilon yes but how much time is that in comparison to allocating memory dynamically to adjust for different move to's and we have no idea what is going on behind the scenes with moveto vs moveby.  Tests will be needed to see which one truly is better

Comment: @Epsilon bear in mind that 60 moveTo SKActions each lasting 1/60 second vs. a single action lasting 1 second, probably doesn't use much more CPU, as the CPU will still need to test in every game loop cycle if the longer SKAction has completed. There will probably b differences, but I suspect they won't be dramatic and will probably have no impact on game play.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon my initial concern was how smoothly the character will move and how well you can control its speed. You see overly concerned with CPU usage which is most likely not an issue here.

Comment: @Epsilon the character will move the same regardless of which function we use,  I actually took back the idea of even using a repeat control and just multiply the moveby amount and the duration amount to cover for any lag inconsistencies

Comment: so I just optimized both methods as best as I could,  my verdict is they both end up running about the same, so do whatever you feel comfortable with

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Just implemented this (each touch of a button gives a repeat forever on a moveBy 400 in 1s) and when I just touch and let go of the button, it registers the touch but generates no movement. Not tried it on a device - could this be a simulator thing?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Don't think so - removing it in touchesEnded for that button and touchesMoved if the touch location is no longer in that button.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon OK - it's a simulator thing. My 12" Macbook isn't very powerful.