# Cant make Spritenode move in one direction forever?

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, skaction

Ok, this is frustrating because this should not be this hard. Whenever The user has their finger down, I need my sprite node to move forever in one direction. Here I create my sprite node

```
character.size = CGSize(width: 58, height: 139)
        character.color = UIColor.red
        character.position = CGPoint(x: (scene?.size.width)!/2, y: (scene?.size.height)!/2)
        character.zPosition = 3
        character.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: character.size)
        character.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        character.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        character.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
```

Then in touches began, I have tried applying a force directly and having a repeating skaction that is removed when touches ended, however using SKaction.moveBy, the node moves 10 then snaps back to the original position:

```
override public func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touch!")
        isTouching = true
        let touch = touches.first!
//        
        let movement = CGVector(
            dx: 10,
            dy: 1
        )
        let move = SKAction.moveBy(x: character.position.x+10, y: 0, duration: 1)
        //let move = SKAction.applyForce(movement, duration: 0.5)
        character.run(SKAction.repeatForever(move), withKey: "moving")
```

I am using the character.position.x so I don't know why it is not just moving forever to the right. How can I make the node move continuously in a direction?

Comment: Is this similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/41220072/1430420?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, an action will move a node from one starting point to the end point. If you repeat it, it will *teleport* the node to where it was at the beginning, and move it again to its final position. Conclusion - `SKAction` is not suitable for this.

You have a few options:

1) Affecting on sprite's position property manually - eg. inside of an update: method, you will increment/decrement position.x/position.y property over time.

```
sprite.position.y += 1
```

2) You will apply force in every frame inside of an update: method

```
sprite.physicsBody.applyForce(CGVector(dx:dxValue, dy:dyValue)
```

3) Affecting on physics body velocity vector directly:

```
sprite.physicsBody.velocity = CGVector(dx:dxValue, dy:dyValue)
```

Probably you could go with applying an impulse to the node, but I think that more appropriate for your situation is to apply force each frame.

Hope this make sense and is helpful.