# iOS/Swift: Using touchesmoved to move SpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to make some game with using **touchesMoved** function. As you can see, when you press right site of screen, object must go to the right etc. But it works with lags. Any ideas how to fix it would be really helpful. Thanks.

```
    for touch in touches{

        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if (location.x <= ship.position.x){
        ship.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: ship.position.x-10.0, duration: 0.01))
        }
        else{
            ship.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: ship.position.x+10.0, duration: 0.01))
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by ‘lags’? Bear in mind that `touchesMoved` is only called when your touch actually moves. If you just touch the screen and don’t move your finger, it won’t get called.

Comment: It is most likely lagging due to you adding a ton of moveTo actions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Button continually call a function when held down (SpriteKit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220072/how-to-make-a-button-continually-call-a-function-when-held-down-spritekit)