# SpriteKit sprite flickers on collision

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have this onscreen joystick which moves sprite around by changing it's position and it works well. I've made some walls for the sprite to collide with (using Physics). And it's not going further as expected but if I keep going into a wall sprite seems to flicker (change it's position for a millisecond and going right back)

```
 override func update(deltaTime seconds: TimeInterval) {
     cNode.position = CGPoint(x: playerCurrentPosition.x + xChange, 
                              y: playerCurrentPosition.y + yChange)
 }
```

Did some more debugging and it seems for one update sprite's position is incorrect:

```
 pos Y: -19.168764114379883
 pos Y: -19.164892196655273
 pos Y: -19.16112518310547
 pos Y: -29.928884506225586. <---
 pos Y: -19.15281105041504
 pos Y: -19.148771286010742
```

**Update**:

Okay, I've tried moving with move By like so :

```
print("[", xChange,", ",yChange,"]", cNode.position.y)
cNode.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: xChange, y: yChange, duration: 1/60))
```

And I got the same flicker on Y position:

```
            xChange,                yChange,        cNode.position.y
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -19.026506423950195
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -19.026336669921875
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -19.02557373046875
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -29.92888641357422
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -29.928884506225586
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -29.928884506225586
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -29.928884506225586
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -19.02621841430664
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -19.025728225708008
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -19.02647590637207
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -19.02564811706543
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -19.02585792541504
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -19.02660369873047
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -19.025630950927734
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -19.026046752929688
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -19.026309967041016
    [ -0.08623046134167665 ,  0.4925081801724735 ] -19.025686264038086
```

**Update 2:**

I've made a recording of the issue: [Here](https://media.giphy.com/media/lz7HONn2AFzxufh7sK/giphy.gif)

**Update 3:**

It seems my outer green rect had some collision masks, I removed those and it got better, but still there's some bouncing, have a look: [Here](https://media.giphy.com/media/kvdHt0eT9XGOLPqRUc/giphy.gif)
(red box is pinned to the green one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly the fact that you are using code - triggered by the joystick - to set the sprite's position directly yet the sprite and the wall cannot overlap due to their physics bodies 'collisionBitMask` settings.

So the sprite is up against the wall and you use the joystick to move the sprite towards the wall. You update the sprite's position which places it overlapping the wall node. The SK engine never saw the 2 nodes begin to overlap but suddenly sees that these nodes overlap massively when they shouldn't and attempts to move them via an impulse so that they don't overlap anymore, causing the sprite to 'jump' to a new position where it doesn't overlap and so it appears to flicker.

You could avoid this my using an SKAction to move the sprite in response to the joystick input which I think will let the SK engine trap the collision between the wall and the spite as soon as they start to overlap and you could use contact detection to then stop the movement.

Comment: Ah, that's certainly makes sense. Yesterday I tried doing so, but had the same problem. Let me try once more, and I will update the question with the results. Thanks!

Comment: If you use a `moveTo` SKAction, you'll probably hit the same problem i.e. the sprite suddenly appears in the middle of the wall. Try a `moveBy` for a small distance with a duration of 1/60s. See this discussion here ; https://stackoverflow.com/a/41220965/1430420

Comment: Got the same results... I updated the post with details

Comment: That’s odd - the y position is changing by 10 points from -19 to -29 yet the y change is only 0.49. Is the print and the moveBy next to each other (in update()?) as you show?

Comment: I've added a video with the issue. Also it's the same without the print

Comment: I assume that the red area are the walls; it looks like the small red rectangle within the green square is the actual node that for the most part is prevented from going over the wall - is that right? Do you always get the flicker/jump when trying to move ‘into’ the wasp? Does it happen for all walls or just some of them?

Comment: yeah, the small red is the child node of the green one, I removed collisions for the green one, and also the red one is pinned. Happens for the all walls..

Comment: So the joystick is moving the green square and the red rectangle is attached to the green square with a physics joint pin?

Comment: I appreciate that you still have problems, but I'm sure that it;s the combination of directly setting the sprite's position combined with the physics body collision detection that is causing the issue. I can;t think of a way to investigate further from my end unless you are able to post a complete code sample that exhibits the problem? I see that you have accepted my answer - have you been able to fix the problem?

Comment: Thanks Steve for your help and sorry for bothering for so long. I fiddled a bit with contact and collision masks, also it seemed outer box had some collisions set to walls and that might have been the case. Although there's a small jump left, but I can live with that. Cheers!